# JavaScript changing iframe src causes http request conflict and iframe doesn't reload

Tags: javascript, html, http, iframe, request

I am new to web dev and have  done a lot of research on my problem, but I still feel stuck:

What I am trying to achieve:
Pass data via URL parameters to an iframe src to be used in the iframe document. The parent page and the iframe are on different domains.

Setup:
I  can have one or multiple iframe(s) with a src=”www.example.com”. After the DOM is fully loaded, I try to change the iframe(s) src in order to append some query parameters.
I am using pure JS to get the initial iframe(s) src > concatonate it with the query parameters > save the new URL in variable > change the iframe(s) src to the URL  from the variable.

Problem:
Sometimes the iframe src doesn’t change – seems to be related to the internet  connection. Every few refreshes javascript will not succeed changing the src, but doesn’t throw any errors.

My troubleshooting:
If I inspect the page and go to Network (Chrome), I can see  there are 2 HTTP requests for the iframe: first with the initial src and  second with the new src (even if the JS dones’t succeed changing it).

From here I encountered 3 scenarios:

1. First http request is cancelled and the second is finished – everything is fine – src is changed and data is passed.
2. both http requests remain in ‘pending’ status – the src is change and data is passed.
3. first http request is finished before the second one is started. The second one remains in ‘pending’ status – this is the problem – the src doesn’t change, it remains to the old one even though JS seems to have executed properly.

I understand that when the src of an iframe is changed it should cause the iframe to reload, thus triggering the second http request. However, when scenario 3 happens the iframe doesn’t reload. It’s like an http request ‘conflict’ (not sure if it's the correct way to put it).

Why changing the src would not properly reload the iframe consistently?

I appreciate any suggestions, best practices or possible alternatives to make this work.

Here is my code. I've put comments to describe what I intend to do:

```
paramToPass = ['parma1', 'param2', 'param3']
if (paramToPass) {
    var myIframe = 'myIframeClass'; // define what iframes to find
    var iframes = document.getElementsByClassName(myIframe); // get all iframes from the page with desired class
    var paramStr = paramToPass.join('&'); // create the query parameter string
    var iframesElm;
    for (iframesElm = 0;  iframesElm < iframes.length; iframesElm++) {
        var initialSrc = iframes[iframesElm].getAttribute('src'); // find the initial src of the iframe
        if(initialSrc.indexOf("?") > -1) { // if initialSrc already contains parameters
            var newSrc = initialSrc + '&' + paramStr; // concatonate initial src with parameters
            iframes[iframesElm].src = newSrc; // change the iframe src
            // iframes[iframesElm].setAttribute('src', newSrc); // alternative to change iframe src
        } else { // if initialSrc doesn't contain parameters
            var newSrc = initialSrc + '?' + paramStr; // concatonate initial src with parameters
            iframes[iframesElm].src = newSrc; // change iframe src
            // iframes[iframesElm].setAttribute('src', newSrc); // alternative to change iframe src
        }; 
    };
};
```

Thank you!

**EDIT:**

New, working code. For wider browser compatibility, I've included polyfill for [Array.from()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from#Polyfill) and [forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach#Polyfill):

```
paramToPass = ['parma1', 'param2', 'param3']        
        if (paramToPass.length > 0) {
            var iframes = document.getElementsByClassName(myIframe);
            var paramToPassStr = paramToPass.join('&');
            Array.from(iframes).forEach(function(iframe) {
                iframe.onload = function() { // execute after the iframe is loaded. Prevents http request conflict
                    var initialSrc = iframe.src;
                    var sep = initialSrc.indexOf("?") > -1 ? "&" : "?"; // choose separator based on whether or not params already exist in the initialSrc
                    var newSrc = initialSrc + sep + paramToPassStr;
                    iframe.src = newSrc;
                    console.log('iframe reload');
                    iframe.onload = null; // stops the infinite reload loop
                };
            });
        } else { // paramToPass array is empty, throw error
            console.log('no paramToPassStr to pass found')
        };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should probably put the code to reload the iframe into its `onload` handler, so it runs after the iframe successfully loaded the first time. Then there won't be any conflict.

```
Array.from(iframes).forEach(iframe => iframe.onload = () => {
    var initialSrc = this.src;
    var sep = initialSrc.indexOf("?") > -1 ? "&" : "?";
    var newSrc = initialSrc + sep + paramStr;
    this.src = newSrc;
    this.onload = null;
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! I've just tried this but it gets into an infinite loop - the iframe keep reloading. How can I stop it? Shouldn't it stop once all elements from 'iframes' array have been processed?

Comment: I updated the answer. WHen it's reloading the iframe it removes the `onload` property.

Comment: Thanks! Seems to be working now, I need to to do some more testing for cross browser compatibility through. For completeness of the answer: there is a syntax typo on line 3: colon should be replaced by question mark after '-1'. Also, I've replaced `this.src` with `iframe.src` as `this.` was referring to the object this function is part of. Finally  I've checked on internet explorer 10 and it throws a syntax error for line `Array.from(iframes).forEach(iframe => iframe.onload = () => {`I believe it's because `Array.from` is not supported by IE10. I will look for an alternative.

Comment: It's because arrow functions aren't supported by IE10. Use old-style anonymous functions.

Comment: See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from#Polyfill for a polyfill for `Array.from()`

Comment: great, I change to old style functions and check polyfill. I will revert here after finishing testing and update the code. Thanks for your help!

Comment: hey, I've tested in all major browsers and worked fine. I marked your answer as accepted. Thank you for your help!